# Protected method is not visible in child class

Tags: apex

I am trying to test protected method but it showing error "method not visible". In test class when i am calling parent protected setvalue method its giving error, it would be also helpful if anybody give a brief description for protected method use cases.

```
public virtual class student {
    public integer age;
    public string name;

    protected void setvalue(integer val, string nm){

        age=val;
        name=nm;
    }
}
```

//---------------

```
@istest
public class teststudent extends student{

    public static testmethod void main(){

        student st = new student();
        st.setvalue(22,'Aasha');   // here i am facing error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) explains that protected:

> This means that the method or variable is visible to any
>   inner classes in the defining Apex class, and to the classes that
>   extend the defining Apex class. You can only use this access modifier
>   for instance methods and member variables. Note that it is strictly
>   more permissive than the default (private) setting, just like Java.

A use case is to share some functionality defined in a method in the base class with an extending class, but to not have that functionality visible to users of the base or extension class. So it's a way of sharing internal implementation detail without changing the public signature.

Very occasionally it can be necessary to invoke a protected or private method from a test and the [@TestVisible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) allows that to be done.

Comment: when i replace isTest with testVisible it is again giving error testmethod must be in test class. So is their any way to run this in test class.

Comment: @AmitChaudhary The @TestVisible goes on the `setvalue` method - please read the link I provided.